# Limitations on naming a framework in an academic setting

Tags: publications, data

I am designing a framework in an AI related field of study which has a particularly difficult name properly abbreviate. I was wondering if it is appropriate if I were to name it something that doesn't necessarily borrow from the actual name of the framework but conceptually represents what it does.

For instance, if I were designing a framework to attack certain systems in order to test their defenses, being the big Greek mythology nerd that I am, I'd love to name it Ares despite what the actual abbreviation might look like.

The question is then, whether or not I'm free to name my framework however I like as long as there is a reasonable conceptual explanation for it and if not, then what limitations exist on naming conventions.

Comment: I think you need to say more. I'm having trouble understanding. Is the abbreviation offensive? Ares Simulation System: ASS? There are few words (abbreviations, acronyms) that are really off limits these days.

Comment: No the abbreviation simply doesn't sound like a real word nor does it roll off the tongue no matter how I spin it. Something like GENMAR for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pretty much name your tools whatever you want to. There is, for example, a group out there that made a methylome database and analysis pipeline and naturally chose to call it "[MethPipe](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0081148)". There are also plenty of tools with the naming convention you've described here; nobody will really care if you're using a descriptor than an acronym.

However, you should consider if there are other tools out there with similar names and how easy yours will be to lookup online. For instance, everyone and their postdoc has a tool called "Prism" in the biology sphere, and it can be very difficult to find the specific "Prism" tool you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Doing occasionally nigh-unspeakable things to a tool/method/...'s name in order to arrive at an interesting acronym is a proud(?) scientific tradition. See for example [this list](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26629805_Methods_Acronyms_-_The_Witty_Side_of_Science) of (mostly NMR-related) abbreviations, just off the top of my head. Not everyone likes it - in bioinformatics there is/was the [JABBA "award"](http://www.acgt.me/blog/2013/6/23/introducing-jabba-just-another-bogus-bioinformatics-acronym.html) for the most "creative" acronyms - and if it's too much of a stretch it might be hard to find your method when searching for it, but it's not likely there's going to be major issues with you naming your method something memorable.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment, I think you are free to name it as you please. An abbreviation or acronym that is (still) very offensive to some would be an exception, though standards change.

But, giving a name that has a more or less pronounceable abbreviation is not an issue. Users are free to use the full name or the abbreviation, or make up their own abbreviation, in any case.

Note also that some names of things weren't assigned by their creators.

But, give it a name that works for you. Change it if you get fiercely negative feedback. In another realm, nobody cares that FBI or SEC don't roll off the tongue.